# Delphi 7 And __ArrayList

Tags: c#, delphi, com, delphi-7

**In Delphi 7:**

How do I get read an array list that is returned in a COM DLL made ​​in C #?

I tried this:

```
var
  products: IList;
begin
  products := MyClass.Products() as IList;
  //...
end;
```

This mode is recomended in documentation, but in Delphi 7, I cant apply a for or while or whatever in my products variable.

My intention is to read the results and store it in my treeview.

How can I do that?

**Note**: IList is derived from mscorlib_TLB.pas and apparently in Delphi 7 there is no way to sweep or count as occurs in more recent versions of Delphi

Comment: The `Count` property should be inherited from the [`ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface, so I think that `(Products as ICollection).Count` should give you the element count. The rest might be about indexed [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. I mean something [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/VFp3ndz9).

Comment: Why not make that an answer TLama? And then no need for pastebin

Answer (score 1):

With `IList` you call `GetEnumerator`, inherited from the `IEnumerable` interface, to obtain an `IEnumerator` interface and iterate over that. In pseudo-code:

```
enumerator := products.GetEnumerator;
while enumerator.MoveNext do
  DoStuff(enumerator.Current);
```

I guess you'll need to cast `Current` to something more useful in your code. And you'll also likely need to cast your `IList` to `IEnumerable` as mentioned by @TLama.

Comment: If you import mscorlib type library, you'll see that `IList` inherits there from `IDispatch`. That's why I've suggested `as` cast.

Comment: Well, it is pseudocode. I guess if you want more help you'll need to explain precisely what your code looks like and what "not works" means.

Comment: Thanks mr @DavidHeffernan. I know this is a pseudo-code. I'm reading the documentation and trying to follow your line of reasoning.